# Create a File in COBOL

Tags: file, cobol

Using COBOL, how can I create a line sequential .dat file if a file of the specified name does not exist?

Comment: Which COBOL dialect are you using? The `OPTIONAL` phrase when used with `SELECT` may not be supported on ouput of line sequential files for all COBOL dialects.

Comment: Why do you think it may be a problem if xxxx.dat does not exist before running your program? If xxxx.dat does not exist at the start, it will at the end. If it does exist at the start, at the end all the data will be "new" data. This is all very "normal", so do you mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either

```
OPEN OUTPUT fd
```

which will create a new file every time **erasing any existent data**, or add the **OPTIONAL** keyword to the FILE-CONTROL SELECT phrase.

```
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
    select OPTIONAL data-file
        assign to file-name
        organization is line sequential
        file status is data-file-status.
```

and use **OPEN I-O data-file**.  COBOL will prep an empty file for first write if need be.

See http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#does-opencobol-support-isam for an arbitrary example (not line sequential, but should get the point across).

Listing (and output) included here for completeness:

```
OCOBOL >>SOURCE FORMAT IS FIXED
      *> ***************************************************************
      *><* ================
      *><* indexing example
      *><* ================
      *><* :Author:    Brian Tiffin
      *><* :Date:      17-Feb-2009
      *><* :Purpose:   Fun with Indexed IO routines
      *><* :Tectonics: cobc -x indexing.cob
      *> ***************************************************************
       identification division.
       program-id. indexing.

       environment division.
       configuration section.

       input-output section.
       file-control.
          select optional indexing
          assign to "indexing.dat"
          organization is indexed
          access mode is dynamic
          record key is keyfield of indexing-record
          alternate record key is splitkey of indexing-record
              with duplicates
          .

      *> ** OpenCOBOL does not yet support split keys **
      *>  alternate record key is newkey
      *>      source is first-part of indexing-record
      *>                last-part of indexing-record
      *>      with duplicates

       data division.
       file section.
       fd indexing.
       01 indexing-record.
          03 keyfield          pic x(8).
          03 splitkey.
             05 first-part     pic 99.
             05 middle-part    pic x.
             05 last-part      pic 99.
          03 data-part         pic x(54).

       working-storage section.
       01 display-record.
          03 filler            pic x(4)  value spaces.
          03 keyfield          pic x(8).
          03 filler            pic xx    value spaces.
          03 splitkey.
             05 first-part     pic z9.
             05 filler         pic x     value space.
             05 middle-part    pic x.
             05 filler         pic xx    value all "+".
             05 last-part      pic z9.
          03 filler            pic x(4)  value all "-".
          03 data-part         pic x(54).

      *> control break
       01 oldkey               pic 99x99.

      *> In a real app this should well be two separate flags
       01 control-flag         pic x.
          88 no-more-duplicates          value high-value
             when set to false is              low-value.
          88 no-more-records             value high-value
             when set to false is              low-value.

      *> ***************************************************************
       procedure division.

      *> Open optional index file for read write
       open i-o indexing

      *> populate a sample database
       move "1234567800a01some 12345678 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "8765432100a01some 87654321 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "1234876500a01some 12348765 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "8765123400a01some 87651234 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record

       move "1234567900b02some 12345679 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "9765432100b02some 97654321 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "1234976500b02some 12349765 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "9765123400b02some 97651234 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record

       move "1234568900c13some 12345689 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "9865432100c13some 98654321 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "1234986500c13some 12349865 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record
       move "9865123400c13some 98651234 data here" to indexing-record
       perform write-indexing-record

      *> close it ... not necessary, but for the example
       close indexing

      *> clear the record space for this example
       move spaces to indexing-record

      *> open the data file again
       open i-o indexing

      *> read all the duplicate 00b02 keys
       move 00 to first-part of indexing-record
       move "b" to middle-part of indexing-record
       move 02 to last-part of indexing-record

      *> using read key and then next key / last key compare
       set no-more-duplicates to false
       perform read-indexing-record
       perform read-next-record
           until no-more-duplicates

      *> read by key of reference ... the cool stuff
       move 00 to first-part of indexing-record
       move "a" to middle-part of indexing-record
       move 02 to last-part of indexing-record

      *> using start and read next
       set no-more-records to false
       perform start-at-key
       perform read-next-by-key
           until no-more-records

      *> read by primary key of reference
       move "87654321" to keyfield of indexing-record

      *>
       set no-more-records to false
       perform start-prime-key
       perform read-previous-by-key
           until no-more-records

      *> and with that we are done with indexing sample
       close indexing

       goback.
      *> ***************************************************************

      *><* Write paragraph
       write-indexing-record.
         write indexing-record
             invalid key
                 display
                     "rewrite key: " keyfield of indexing-record
                 end-display
                   rewrite indexing-record
                       invalid key
                           display
                               "really bad key: "
                               keyfield of indexing-record
                           end-display
                   end-rewrite
         end-write
       .

      *><* read by alternate key paragraph
       read-indexing-record.
           display "Reading: " splitkey of indexing-record end-display
           read indexing key is splitkey of indexing-record
         invalid key
             display
                "bad read key: " splitkey of indexing-record
             end-display
               set no-more-duplicates to true
           end-read
       .

      *><* read next sequential paragraph
       read-next-record.
           move corresponding indexing-record to display-record
           display display-record end-display
           move splitkey of indexing-record to oldkey

           read indexing next record
               at end set no-more-duplicates to true
               not at end
                   if oldkey not equal splitkey of indexing-record
                       set no-more-duplicates to true
                   end-if
           end-read
       .

      *><* start primary key of reference paragraph
       start-prime-key.
           display "Prime < " keyfield of indexing-record end-display
           start indexing
              key is less than
                  keyfield of indexing-record
              invalid key
                  display
                      "bad start: " keyfield of indexing-record
                  end-display
                  set no-more-records to true
              not invalid key
                  read indexing previous record
                      at end set no-more-records to true
                  end-read
           end-start
       .

      *><* read previous by key of reference paragraph
       read-previous-by-key.
           move corresponding indexing-record to display-record
           display display-record end-display

           read indexing previous record
               at end set no-more-records to true
           end-read
       .
      *><* start alternate key of reference paragraph
       start-at-key.
           display "Seeking >= " splitkey of indexing-record end-display
           start indexing
              key is greater than or equal to
                  splitkey of indexing-record
              invalid key
                  display
                      "bad start: " splitkey of indexing-record
                  end-display
                  set no-more-records to true
              not invalid key
                  read indexing next record
                      at end set no-more-records to true
                  end-read
           end-start
       .

      *><* read next by key of reference paragraph
       read-next-by-key.
           move corresponding indexing-record to display-record
           display display-record end-display

           read indexing next record
               at end set no-more-records to true
           end-read
       .
       end program indexing.
      *><*
      *><* Last Update: 20090220
```

which outputs:

```
Reading: 00b02
    12345679   0 b++ 2----some 12345679 data here
    97654321   0 b++ 2----some 97654321 data here
    12349765   0 b++ 2----some 12349765 data here
    97651234   0 b++ 2----some 97651234 data here
    12345679   0 b++ 2----some 12345679 data here
    97654321   0 b++ 2----some 97654321 data here
    12349765   0 b++ 2----some 12349765 data here
    97651234   0 b++ 2----some 97651234 data here
    12345679   0 b++ 2----some 12345679 data here
    97654321   0 b++ 2----some 97654321 data here
    12349765   0 b++ 2----some 12349765 data here
    97651234   0 b++ 2----some 97651234 data here
Seeking >= 00a02
    12345679   0 b++ 2----some 12345679 data here
    97654321   0 b++ 2----some 97654321 data here
    12349765   0 b++ 2----some 12349765 data here
    97651234   0 b++ 2----some 97651234 data here
    12345679   0 b++ 2----some 12345679 data here
    97654321   0 b++ 2----some 97654321 data here
    12349765   0 b++ 2----some 12349765 data here
    97651234   0 b++ 2----some 97651234 data here
    12345679   0 b++ 2----some 12345679 data here
    97654321   0 b++ 2----some 97654321 data here
    12349765   0 b++ 2----some 12349765 data here
    97651234   0 b++ 2----some 97651234 data here
    12345689   0 c++13----some 12345689 data here
    98654321   0 c++13----some 98654321 data here
    12349865   0 c++13----some 12349865 data here
    98651234   0 c++13----some 98651234 data here
    12345689   0 c++13----some 12345689 data here
    98654321   0 c++13----some 98654321 data here
    12349865   0 c++13----some 12349865 data here
    98651234   0 c++13----some 98651234 data here
    12345689   0 c++13----some 12345689 data here
    98654321   0 c++13----some 98654321 data here
    12349865   0 c++13----some 12349865 data here
    98651234   0 c++13----some 98651234 data here
Prime < 87654321
    87651234   0 a++ 1----some 87651234 data here
    12349865   0 c++13----some 12349865 data here
    12349765   0 b++ 2----some 12349765 data here
    12348765   0 a++ 1----some 12348765 data here
    12345689   0 c++13----some 12345689 data here
    12345679   0 b++ 2----some 12345679 data here
    12345678   0 a++ 1----some 12345678 data here
```

on any first runs, where indexing.dat does not exist. Subsequent runs have the same output with:

```
rewrite key: 12345678
rewrite key: 87654321
rewrite key: 12348765
rewrite key: 87651234
rewrite key: 12345679
rewrite key: 97654321
rewrite key: 12349765
rewrite key: 97651234
rewrite key: 12345689
rewrite key: 98654321
rewrite key: 12349865
rewrite key: 98651234
```

prepended, as the WRITE INVALID KEY clause triggers a REWRITE to allow overwriting key and data.

Comment: That helps very much. I wish IO would work with line sequential, but it will work.

Comment: It should work with line sequential files.  Additionally, a rewrite should work as well updating the previous record successfully read.

Comment: @Buggabill; Yeah sorry, I wondered if the different file structure would be confusing.  But, I did try to explain with _... for an arbitrary example (not line sequential, but should get the point across)._  I was hoping for focus on OPTIONAL and how second runs can differ.

Comment: `OPEN I-O file-descriptor` DOES work for OPTIONAL LINE SEQUENTIAL (at least in OpenCOBOL).  Never tested REWRITE under those conditions.  OPTIONAL OPEN I-O will allow empty read passes and append on write.

Comment: I made a mistake. You're all right. Sequential line files will work with OPEN IO, and OPEN OUTPUT will create the file if it does not already exist. My program works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is very old here. But I was still having the same problem today and after a few hours I discover that GnuCOBOL 2.0 with OpenCobolIDE 4.7.6 that I am using generates error 35 when trying to use OPEN EXTEND. I solved it in a not very elegant way, but it works perfectly. I am sharing the solution I found.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. CREATFIL.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT FD-VIRTUAL ASSIGN TO "CADFILE.TXT"
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL
       ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
       FILE STATUS IS WS-GET-ERROR.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  FD-VIRTUAL.
   01  FS-BOOK.
       05 NOME PIC X(40).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  WS-GET-ERROR      PIC XX.

   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  TB-VIRTUAL.
       05  TB-BOOK.
           10 LS-NOME    PIC X(40).
   77  LS-ENTER          PIC X.
   77  WS-RESP           PIC A VALUE "Y".

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       OPEN EXTEND FD-VIRTUAL.
       IF WS-GET-ERROR = "35" 
          OPEN OUTPUT FD-VIRTUAL
       END-IF
       IF WS-GET-ERROR = "00"
          PERFORM UNTIL UPPER-CASE(WS-RESP) NOT = "Y"
             DISPLAY X"0D"
             DISPLAY "Name: " WITH NO ADVANCING
             ACCEPT LS-NOME
             WRITE FS-BOOK FROM TB-BOOK
             DISPLAY "More record (Y) for YES " WITH NO ADVANCING
             DISPLAY "- any key for NOT: " 
                WITH NO ADVANCING
             ACCEPT WS-RESP
             IF UPPER-CASE(WS-RESP) NOT = "Y"
                EXIT PERFORM
             END-IF
          END-PERFORM
       END-IF.

       CLOSE FD-VIRTUAL.

       DISPLAY X"0D".
       DISPLAY "Press <ENTER> to finish... " WITH NO ADVANCING.
       ACCEPT LS-ENTER.
       STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM CREATFIL.
```

Observe the instruction

```
OPEN EXTEND FD-VIRTUAL.
IF WS-GET-ERROR = "35" 
   OPEN OUTPUT FD-VIRTUAL
END-IF
```